# Can DotNetOpenAuth be used within a Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, dotnetopenauth

I have used DotNetOpenAuth previously in an ASP.net website and it works fine. But now I wanted to create a Silverlight app. Unfortunately I can't reference DotNetOpenAuth.dll, since this is not compiled against the Silverlight CLR. Is there a solution to use open authentication from Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth currently has this as an open issue for the group. [Here's the link for the post](http://dotnetopenauth.uservoice.com/pages/14800-general/suggestions/146009-create-a-silverlight-openid-control) and [here is the link for the tracked item.](http://trac.dotnetopenauth.net:8000/ticket/28) There is [this control](http://mark.mymonster.nl/2009/07/28/openid-user-control-in-silverlight-part-1-ui-design/) a third party created, however it appears to me like it is not very secure so use it at your own risk. I only mention it because it could be a potential band-aid depending on the needs of your project.

Comment: I'll add to Kavet's security comment: if you're looking for OpenID within a Silverlight application, there's no security there at all because that's not what OpenID was designed to secure. OAuth applies to Silverlight apps.